# Is there any way to my load a local Js file dynamically in https://web.whatsapp.com/?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I want to load a Local Js file dynamically in https://web.whatsapp.com/.

My Project Folder Structure is....

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwaJakw4KTunZi1Kd1d0QlR3R1U
```

I have tried to do it using following....

manifest.json file

```
{
"name": "Assignment 1.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",
"web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "test.js"]
}
```

test.js file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function () {
    return jQuery('
    ').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    };
    var html = $("html").outerHTML();
    alert(html);
    });
```

My Created Extension in Chrome Browser.....

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwaJakw4KTunRnVpNDFySFo0cmM
```

Code Used to Inject Js file in Whatsapp web page.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "chrome-extension://cgcghfdjhjcplknknigoklaleahdfllp/";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Error in Console while injecting a Js file....

Error message: -

"Denying load of chrome-extension://cgcghfdjhjcplknknigoklaleahdfllp/. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED"

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaJakw4KTuna1g2OENlTEh2ckk/view?usp=sharing
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: web_accessible_resources doesn't *inject* anything, it only allows direct access from web pages. Why did you chose it instead of a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) which can be injected either automatically or manually from an internal extension script (in the background page or popup, for example)?

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), as wOxxOm suggested.

Comment: This looks like a question which is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve. What you have described "load a Local Js file dynamically" is not normally accomplished in the way you appear to be going about it.

Comment: How is the code you show which creates a `<script>` element executed? There is nothing in your *manifest.json* which would cause any code to execute. In addition, `chrome-extension://cgcghfdjhjcplknknigoklaleahdfllp/` is just the beginning of the URL needed to access a file in your extension (if it is the right identifier for your extension). At a minimum, you would still need a file name added to that URL segment.

Comment: I have used with the content script, too. I can't get any output. It shows me Denying load of chrome-extension://cgcghfdjhjcplknknigoklaleahdfllp/. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Ugh. I don't understand what you're trying to load. Find and adapt any simple chrome extension with a content script if you don't want to explain here.

Comment: In https://web.whatsapp.com/ case, some of the Dom elements are loading dynamically which can't read using my customize Js file.Would you please suggest me where should I put my jQuery Code (Under Which Event)?  jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return jQuery('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};
setTimeout($(window).load(function() {
    var html = $("html").outerHTML();
    alert(html);
}), 3000);